# (MUI v5) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I am using a mui `textfield` to submit data to the database. I want to make the `textfield` focus when the component is mounted using `useRef`. However, I kept receiving the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')`.

My code:

```
const StyledTooltip = styled(Tooltip)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...
}));

const CreateBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...
}));

const LoginTextField = styled(TextField)({
  ...
});

function Create () {

  const inputRef = useRef();

  const [openCreate, setOpenCreate] = useState(false);

  const toggleCreateWindow = () => {
    setOpenCreate(!openCreate);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Modal aria-labelledby='create' aria-describedby='create' open={openCreate} onClose={toggleCreateWindow} 
        closeAfterTransition BackdropComponent={Backdrop} BackdropProps={{ timeout: 500 }}>
        <Fade in={openCreate}>
          <CreateBox>
            <LoginTextField label='Content' variant='outlined' placeholder="Writing something about Japan......" inputRef={inputRef}
              multiline rows={12} maxRows={14} InputLabelProps={{ style: { color: 'white' } }} inputProps={{ style: { color: "white" } }} />
          </CreateBox>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
      <StyledTooltip title='Create'>
        <Fab aria-label='create' onClick={toggleCreateWindow}>
          <EditIcon />
        </Fab>
      </StyledTooltip>
    </>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

Is it an unique issue for MUI `textfield`? Because it works fine with the html `textfield` Anybody has an idea what's wrong with my code? Much appreciated!

Comment: I don’t work with MUi but I believe it should be ‘ref={inputRef}

Comment: How about using
`useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, [inputRef.current])`

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, but it didnt auto focus on the textfield